# How to configure postfix to receive mails and keep them in queue but not sending them out

Tags: linux, postfix

How to configure postfix to only receive mails and put them into local queue but not actually forwarding mails so they keep inside /var/spool/postfix

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a tool like MailHog or MailCatcher if you don't actually intend to send the emails? Such tools are explicitly designed to do what you want - catch all sent mail and display it.

Comment: My goal was to just temp. forward mails — so like a postsuper -h ALL for future incoming mails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try adding the following:**

/etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = 
...
check_recipient_access regexp:/etc/postfix/hold.regexp
```

/etc/postfix/hold.regexp:

```
/^/   HOLD
```

If you want to release all messages on hold, use postsuper:

```
postsuper -H ALL
```

Comment: I'm getting unused parameter for mtpd_recipient_restrictions and check_recipient_acces

Comment: "mtpd"? Did you make that typo in the comment or the config file?

Comment: Can you edit your post to include your main.cf file?

Comment: Oh dear. to stupit to copy paste

Comment: Is that to say that it's now working? :)